# SASS compiler not adding to include path

Tags: ember.js, sass

I'm using the very popular [`ember-cli-sass`](https://www.npmjs.org/package/ember-cli-sass) add-on for Ember CLI. Out of the box it works well, however, in the documentation it describes how you can extend the SASS's include path so you can easily import frameworks which you've added:

In the `Brocfile.js`:

```
 var app = new EmberApp({
   sassOptions: {
     includePaths: [
       'bower_components/foundation/scss'
     ]
   }
 });
```

In my situation, I want to use a bootstrap addon for mobile navigation called [`jasny-bootstrap`](http://jasny.github.io/) rather than the foundation framework so I instead use:

```
 var app = new EmberApp({
    sassOptions: {
        includePaths: [
        'bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/scss'
        ]
    },
 });
```

I then include the full library by adding an **import** directive:

```
 @import "jasny-bootstrap";
```

But instead of happily singing of my achievements I am stuck with the following error:

> /tree_merger-tmp_dest_dir-xqu9CWq6.tmp/app/styles/app.scss:5: file to import not found or unreadable: "jasny-bootstrap"

And yet the directory list of bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/scss is:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff   796  6 May  2014 _alerts-fixed.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  1092  6 May  2014 _button-labels.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  2163  6 May  2014 _fileinput.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff   161  6 May  2014 _grid-container-smooth.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  1861  6 May  2014 _nav-tab-alignment.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  6235  6 May  2014 _navmenu.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff   954  6 May  2014 _offcanvas.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff   364  6 May  2014 _rowlink.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff  2899  6 May  2014 _variables.scss
-rw-r--r--  1 User  staff   384  6 May  2014 jasny-bootstrap.scss
```

As you can see it is readable and using `cat` I can validate that there is indeed nothing wrong with the file `jasny-bootstrap.scss` (it's just a set of imports to the above scss modules).

Comment: Are you sure that's the correct path?  In your file, you have `bower_components/jasny-bootstrap/scss`, but you list the contents of `bower_components/jasny-bootstrap`.

Comment: Sorry typo in my question but not in the code ... I think I am onto the problem now which seems to reside in a destructive options setting in another CLI add-on that I'm using. I'm going to test this a bit more and I'll post the answer assuming I'm correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok it turns out the problem I was running into was hidden away in another add-on. The syntax and approach listed above **is** correct with no modification needed but if you're experiencing a similar result then it's worth looking at your inventory of add-ons which might possibly be setting the **sassOptions** properties themselves.

In my case the `ember-cli-bootstrap-sass` module was destructively setting the sassOptions `includePaths` property so my settings were in vein. I have corrected this and sent in a PR so hopefully this particular add-on will be fixed soon but there could be other SASS related add-ons which behave similarly.